# Unable to fetch data from database using django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-views

I have created one small project in django, in which database is connected with django and having 'Reg' as table name in database.

In models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Reg(models.Model):
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   Email = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   TUID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   Password = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

In views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth    
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Reg
from django.http import HttpResponse


def login(request):
   raw = Reg.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'login.html', {'raw': raw})
```

In login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>hello....</p>
{% for val in raw %}
<p>{{ val.Name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
<p>end...</p>

</body>
</html>
```

expected result should be data from database,

but getting only

hello...
end...

Comment: Are you certain that the data is actually in the database?

Comment: You have a `Reg` model, yet you're querying `Group` model. Please provider a proper description.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to query the correct table.**

Your database is a `Reg`, but you are getting all the elements of `Group`.

Change

```
def login(request):
   raw = Group.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'login.html', {'raw': raw})
```

to

```
def login(request):
   raw = Reg.objects.all()
   return render(request, 'login.html', {'raw': raw})
```